# Node visualization with highlighting the whole route of a certain flow

Tags: javascript, python, p5.js, pyvis

I am trying to visualize the data flow stream for this project. Flows are seperated in layers. I want to draw edges for all the connected nodes and eventually want to highlight the nodes and edges that a certain flow makes from begin to end when a node is clicked. Library for visualization can be in Python or Js

I have tried using the library pyvis in python, until I wanted to change the edges that will light up when a node is certain node is clicked. But could not change the edges that will light up. Is there someway I can change de edges that will get highlighted in the code. Now found a library called p5.js, is there anyone who has experience with this and knows it has flaws?